# UITableView with multidimensional array data from server

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json

I want to fetch data from my web server, and put it into a UITableView. This data includes three values for each row (eMail, Userid, and status (online or not)). Now what's the best way to print out this data on the Webserver that I can convert it into something like an Array in the App? How this works with one simple string I know, and I found JSON-Tutorials on the internet, but the links where you can download JSON for iOS SDK are not available. Or is there an even better way to fetch an Array from a server?
The server has to "print out" a multidimensional array with email, userid and status for each contact.

Thanks very much for help!

`#import <JSON/JSON.h>` doesn't work, the file wasn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (Only available in iOS 5)

Here is a link with a tutorial demonstrating how to use it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

For iOS 4 and below, you should check out the [SBJSON Library](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/).

Using the above methods, you can convert the data into an `NSArray`, of which can be used in a `UITableView`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if the JSON output is not multidimensional (`["test","hello"]`) it works, but how to access the multidimensional array? Now it gives an error..

Comment: I now have this code after the connection: `id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];` and `dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:object, nil];`. How can I access the Strings then?

Comment: Check the class of 'object' and get the strings out of that class as you would normally